# Correct folder names for adding UWP support into my nuget package

Tags: uwp, f#, nuget, f#-fake

I need some help getting my nuget package to support UWP. Our nuget package generation script is written in F#. We've used the folder names "uap" and "uap10.0" but when added to a UWP application the nuget package still defaults to (I believe) the net45 folder's dlls.

We've also tried supporting different architectures as the error reported is that the package doesn't support "win10-arm" -- another folder name we've tried. The project itself builds fine, so I know the dlls are good. It's just the folder structure is wrong on our end, and I'm not sure what is right.

Here is the relevant code (this is the working version:

```
Target "ApiPackage" (fun _ ->
    let androidDir = packagingDir @@ "lib/MonoAndroid"
    let portableDir = packagingDir @@ "lib/net45/"
    let netDir = packagingDir @@ "lib/netstandard2.0"
//    let uwpDirARM = packagingDir @@ "runtimes/win10-arm/native"
//    let uwpDir32 = packagingDir @@ "runtimes/win10-x86/native"
    let iOSDir = packagingDir @@ "lib/monotouch"
    let iOSDir2 = packagingDir @@ "lib/xamarinios"
    CleanDirs [androidDir; portableDir]
    CreateDir artifactsNuGetDir


    trace "Copying Droid Files..."

    let droidFiles =  Directory.GetFiles((androidBuildDir @@ "Release"), "*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    for x in droidFiles do
        printfn "%A " x
    printfn ""
    Copy androidDir droidFiles

    let droidFiles =  Directory.GetFiles((androidBuildDir @@ "Release"), "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    for x in droidFiles do
        printfn "%A " x
    printfn ""
    Copy androidDir droidFiles

    trace "Copying NET Files..."

    let netFiles =  Directory.GetFiles((netBuildDir @@ "Release"), "*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    for x in netFiles do
        printfn "%A " x
    printfn ""
    Copy netDir netFiles

    let netFiles =  Directory.GetFiles((netBuildDir @@ "Release"), "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    for x in netFiles do
        printfn "%A " x
    printfn ""
    Copy netDir netFiles

//    let uwpFiles =  Directory.GetFiles((uwpBuildDir @@ "Release"), "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
//    for x in uwpFiles do
//        printfn "%A " x
//    printfn ""
//    Copy uwpDirARM uwpFiles
//    Copy uwpDir32 uwpFiles

//    let uwpFiles =  Directory.GetFiles((uwpBuildDir @@ "Release"), "*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
//    for x in uwpFiles do
//        printfn "%A " x
//    printfn ""
//    Copy uwpDirARM uwpFiles
//    Copy uwpDir32 uwpFiles

    trace "Copying PCL Files..."

    let pclFiles =  Directory.GetFiles((portableBuildDir @@ "Release"), "*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    for x in pclFiles do
        printfn "%A " x
    printfn ""
    Copy portableDir pclFiles

    let pclFiles =  Directory.GetFiles((portableBuildDir @@ "Release"), "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    for x in pclFiles do
        printfn "%A " x
    printfn ""
    Copy portableDir pclFiles

    let netFiles2 =  Directory.GetFiles((netBuildDir @@ "Release"), "*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    for x in netFiles2 do
        printfn "%A " x
    printfn ""
    Copy portableDir netFiles2

    let netFiles2 =  Directory.GetFiles((netBuildDir @@ "Release"), "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    for x in netFiles2 do
        printfn "%A " x
    printfn ""
    Copy portableDir netFiles2


    let iOSFiles =  Directory.GetFiles((iosBuildDir @@ "Release"), "*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    for x in iOSFiles do
        printfn "%A " x
    printfn ""
    Copy iOSDir iOSFiles

    let iOSFiles =  Directory.GetFiles((iosBuildDir @@ "Release"), "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    for x in iOSFiles do
        printfn "%A " x
    printfn ""
    Copy iOSDir iOSFiles

    let iOSFiles2 =  Directory.GetFiles((iosBuildDir @@ "Release"), "*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    for x in iOSFiles2 do
        printfn "%A " x
    printfn ""
    Copy iOSDir2 iOSFiles2

    let iOSFiles2 =  Directory.GetFiles((iosBuildDir @@ "Release"), "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    for x in iOSFiles2 do
        printfn "%A " x
    printfn ""
    Copy iOSDir2 iOSFiles2

    trace "Creating Nuget Package"

    NuGet (fun p ->
        {p with
            Authors = ["OurCompany"]
            References = ["OurAPI.dll"
                          "OurAPI.Android.dll"
                          "OurAPI.NET.dll"
//                          "OurAPI.UWP.dll"
                          "OurAPI.iOS.dll"]
            Project = projectName
            Description = projectDescription
            OutputPath = artifactsNuGetDir
            Summary = projectSummary
            WorkingDir = packagingDir
            Version = versionNumber
             }) "OurAPI.nuspec"
)
```

The dlls work for all other platforms. Again, we've tried the folder names "uap", "uap10.0", "win10" and naming them based on architecture (the two in the code above.)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The official [NuGet documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/target-frameworks#supported-frameworks) for tfms says that `uap10.0` should work.

I'd suggest to create a standalone repro (nuspec + dummy dlls + dummy uwp project) and report an issue on NuGet.